# trace inequality for positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, trace

Let $A$ be a square real matrix $n \times n$ positive semidefinite. 
Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that
$$
v^TAv \le trace(A) \|v\|^2 
$$
?

Any help will be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: On the left, do you mean $v^T A v$?

Comment: yes sorry! I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the spectral theorem, if $A$ is symmetric it can be written as $Q^T\Lambda Q$ with $\Lambda $ the diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $Q$ an orthogonal matrix. Then we have
$$v^TA v=v^TQ^T\Lambda Qv=w^T\Lambda w,$$
where $w=Qv$. Since $Q$ is orthogonal, we have
$$\|w\|=\langle w,w\rangle =\langle Qv,Qv\rangle =\langle v,Q^TQv\rangle =\langle v,v\rangle = \|v\|,$$
and thus
$$w^T\Lambda w=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iw_i^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\right)\|w\|^2=\operatorname{tr}(A)\|w\|^2=\operatorname{tr}(A)\|v\|^2,$$
because all the eigenvalues are non-negative, and $w_i^2\leq \sum_i w_i^2=\|w\|^2$.

Comment: Why can you assume $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: @B.Mehta I consider that being positive semi-definite is only defined for symmetric matrices. But even if it wasn't the case, any matrix $A$ can be written as $A=\frac{A+A^T}{2}+\frac{A-A^T}{2}$, and the value of $v^TAv$ depends only on the first term, which is symmetric and has the same trace.